# Utilizar await com objeto que implementa o método __await__

Tags: python, python-3.x, async

A partir do `Python 3.5` foi introduzido `async/await` estou implementando alguns objetos aguardáveis mas estou me encontrado com dúvidas segue um exemplo:

```
#!usr/bin/python3                                                                         
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                   

import asyncio                                                                            


class Waiting:                                                                      

    def __await__(self):                                                                  
        print('__await__')                                                                
        yield from asyncio.sleep(3)                                                       
        print('Ok')                                                                       


async def main():                                                                         
    await Waiting()                                                                       


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()                                                       
    try:                                                                                  
        loop.run_until_complete(main())                                                   
    finally:                                                                              
        loop.close()
```

Se o script for executado o resultado será:

```
__await__
Ok
```

Certo o script funcionou mas se tentar implementá-lo utilizando as novas palavras reservadas do `Python 3.5` me deparo com um erro, segue o script:

```
#!usr/bin/python3                                                                         
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  



import asyncio                                                                            

class Waiting:                                                                      

    async def __await__(self):                                                            
        print('__await__')                                                                
        await asyncio.sleep(3)                                                            
        print('Ok')

async def main():                                                                         
    await Waiting() 




if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()                                                       
    try:                                                                                  
        loop.run_until_complete(main())                                                   
    finally:                                                                              
        loop.close()
```

Tornei `__await__` uma co-rotina e alterei `yield from` para `await` e agora ao executar o script recebo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dunder_await.py", line 22, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "dunder_await.py", line 16, in main
    await Waiting()
TypeError: __await__() returned a coroutine
```

Me corrijam se eu estiver errado mas para mim utilizar `await` tenho que definir uma co-rotina e `await` deveria funcionar como `yield from` ou estou errado? E porque estou recebendo esse erro?

Comment: Acho que seria interessante você ocultar o número das linhas no VIM antes de copiar o código, pois isso dificulta testar seu código visto que teríamos que remover os números manualmente.

Comment: PEP 492 diz que `__await__` deve retornar um iterador, mas quando você usa o `await` ele irá retornar uma co-rotina.

Comment: Removi as linhas me desculpe por isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a função mágica `__await__` serve pra você criar um objeto "*awaitável*" da mesma forma que a nova palavra reservada `async def`... Ou seja, se você usa `__await__` você não precisa usar `async def`:

```
class AsyncFunction:
    def __await__(self):
        ...
x = AsyncFunction()
await x
```

é o mesmo que:

```
async def AsyncFunction():
    ...
x = AsyncFunction()
await x
```

Portanto no seu exemplo você precisa escolher. Ou define uma função com `async def` ou cria uma classe com `__await__`, ambas servem para a mesma coisa mas não devem ser usadas em conjunto.